# Script works, captures web page as mht file, but chrome is deleting

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome, mhtml

Download works properly but Google removes it the moment i select "Show in Finder" -

[Removed File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVZi.png)

Safe Browsing set to "No protection (not recommended)"

My goal is to create a simple script that will download and timestamp webarchives that I can run daily with cron or iCal

Ran script seems to work well, downloads web page as archive but Chrome somehow deleted the download

Any help appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the URL of the website to open in Chrome
URL="https://thescottsdaleherald.com/"

# Set the directory to save the web archive file to
SAVE_DIR="$HOME/Desktop/"

# Get the current date in the format "day-month-year"
DATE=$(date +'%H-%d-%m-%Y')

# Open the website in Chrome
open -a "Google Chrome" "$URL"

# Wait for Chrome to load the website
sleep 5

# Get the title of the page
PAGE_TITLE=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to return title of active tab of window 1')

# Replace any commas in the page title with hyphens
PAGE_TITLE=${PAGE_TITLE//,/}

# Save the web archive file with the format "pagetitle,day,month,year.webarchive"
FILE_NAME="$PAGE_TITLE,$DATE.mht"
FULL_PATH="$SAVE_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to save active tab of window 1 in file "'"$FULL_PATH"'" '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AppleScript Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html), a file object is structured as

```
file "VolumeName:FolderName:SubfolderName:FileName"
```

So essentially, your script needs 2 updates:

1. Add volume name to the beginning of SAVE_DIR, e.g.

   `SAVE_DIR="Macintosh SSD/$HOME/Desktop"`

   Ensure to use your own volume name instead
2. When call the FULL_PATH, replace all `/` with `:`

   `...to save active tab of window 1 in file "'"${FULL_PATH//\//:}"'" '`

Comment: Thank you Taylor G!!

That worked

Additionally I changed from MHT to HTML 

FILE_NAME="$PAGE_TITLE,$DATE.html"

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Here is final script - its nice to finally have a daily script - Many Thanks!

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the URL of the website to open in Chrome
URL="https://thescottsdaleherald.com/"

# Set the directory to save the web archive file to
SAVE_DIR="BigSur/$HOME/Desktop"

# Get the current date in the format "day-month-year"
DATE=$(date +'%H-%d-%m-%Y')

# Open the website in Chrome
open -a "Google Chrome" "$URL"

# Wait for Chrome to load the website
sleep 5

# Get the title of the page
PAGE_TITLE=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to return title of active tab of window 1')

# Replace any commas in the page title with hyphens
PAGE_TITLE=${PAGE_TITLE//,/}

# Save the web archive file with the format "pagetitle,day,month,year.html"
FILE_NAME="$PAGE_TITLE,$DATE.html"
FULL_PATH="$SAVE_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to save active tab of window 1 in file "'"${FULL_PATH//\//:}"'" '
```